# boost::program_options multitoken of user-defined types

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I have a custom type (essentially a `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` of `int`) which I want `boost::program_options` to parse a `multitoken()` of.  I've implemented `operator<<`/`operator>>` for it, such that a single parameter of this type compiles fine. However, an `std::vector<MyType>` passed as the `value` parameter `multitoken()` gives me the static compile time error:

```
Target type is neither std::istream`able nor std::wistream`able
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the line of code where you're calling ->multitoken() ?

Comment: Can you also share the implementation of `operator >>` as well as the usage of `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` for completeness? I am not getting any errors when I try to replicate this (Fedora 24 x64 Boost 1.60.0 g++ 6.1.1 and clang++ 3.8.0).